# how do I import module in parent directory?

Tags: python-3.x, package, python-import

How can I import module at parent directory?
In following package, I want to use `techniques` module in main.py

I am using `__all__` to ignore tests when import trade.

```
trade/
    __init__.py
    htmlparser.py
    utils.py
    techniques.py
    tests/
        testdata.json
        main.py
```

__init__.py:

```
__all__ = ["techniques", "utils", "htmlparser"]
```

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? What have you tried? `from trade import techniques`?

Comment: `import sys` `from pathlib import Path` `sys.path.append(str(Path('.').absolute().parent))`

Comment: Does `from trade import techniques` not work? It should if trade is a module in sys.path ...